# Converting a PHP cURL request into node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, api, request

I'm looking at implementing [Summry](http://smmry.com/api), and they only give PHP API connection examples - is there any chance someone could turn it into a JS request for me?

I essentially just want it to parse the text I give it, nothing super fancy yet.

I've tried to see what `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, and `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` match to in a JS request, to no avail. I'm probably looking in the wrong place, however.

**PHP example**

```
$long_article = "Long article text goes here";

$ch = curl_init("http://api.smmry.com/&SM_API_KEY=XXXXXXXXX&SM_LENGTH=14&SM_WITH_BREAK");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Expect:")); // Important do not remove
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "sm_api_input=".$long_article);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$return = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
```

---

**JavaScript replication**

```
...
const request = require('request-promise');
...

const long_article = 'Long article text goes here';
const r = request({
  method: 'POST',
  uri: `http://api.smmry.com/&SM_API_KEY=${process.env.SMMRY_API_KEY}`,
  // headers: { Authorization: 'array(Expect:)' },
  // body: { sm_api_input: long_article },
  json: true,
});

request(r)
.then((parsedBody) => { debug(parsedBody); })
.catch((err) => { debug(err); });
```

The error I'm getting is `{ sm_api_error: 1, sm_api_message: 'INSUFFICIENT VARIABLES' }` so I'm atleast hitting the right URL - so that's a start :)

Thanks in advance!

Ollie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uri that you are passing to `uri` is attempting to use a Query String but you're not correctly formatting the URI you're requesting. A Query String should start with a `?` and separate Key/Value pairs with a `&`. Your Query String is beginning with a `&` instead of a `?`

Change:
`http://api.smmry.com/&SM_API_KEY=${process.env.SMMRY_API_KEY}&SM_LENGTH=14
 &SM_WITH_BREAK`

To:
`http://api.smmry.com/?SM_API_KEY=${process.env.SMMRY_API_KEY}&SM_LENGTH=14&SM_WITH_BREAK`

Additionally, you're creating a request `r` and then passing that request to `request`. That's not how the request-promise module works. When invoking `request(opts)`, the request to the URI will be made immediately and the corresponding Promise will be returned. Once the request is complete any chained handlers will be invoked (`.then()`, `.catch()`, `.finally()`).

```
const request = require('request-promise')
const sm_api_input = 'Long article text goes here'

request({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Expect': '100-continue'
    },
    uri: `http://api.smmry.com/?SM_API_KEY=${process.env.SMMRY_API_KEY}&SM_LENGTH=14&SM_WITH_BREAK`,
    form: {sm_api_input},
    json: true,
    timeout: 20000
})
  .then(body => debug)
  .catch(err => debug)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) It seems the QS is *meant* to be a '&' sign. The other api route seems to work flawlessly `uri: http://api.smmry.com/&SM_API_KEY=${process.env.SMMRY_API_KEY}&SM_URL=http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-oxfordshire-42238343` which is really odd.

I've taken the request above (you need a pesky comma after `uri`), and I'm still getting the cryptic `{ sm_api_error: 1, sm_api_message: 'INSUFFICIENT VARIABLES' }`.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Ollie Are you sure you're passing in all of the required Variables for the Request. Looking at those docs, your URI isn't correct in your `request()` opts. Look again at my answer and look at the updated URI and see if that works.

Comment: I've got it working! anything other than the api key is optional it seems :) 

If you change it from `body` to `form` it works flawlessly. `uri: http://api.smmry.com/&SM_API_KEY=${process.env.SMMRY_API_KEY},
form: { sm_api_input }`,

Thank you so much for your time :) 

If you edit the question to that form + uri, I can mark you as correct :)

Comment: @Ollie ah, the request must be made using a form header instead of `application/json`. I've updated my answer